# Focus on anchor tag not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with focus on anchor. I have below piece of code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabIndex=0> <span> Home </span> </a>
```

I have some width and height for anchor. Have some focus styles like border for anchor.

If i click on anchor, in chrome browser , document.activeElement gives me anchor.

But in IE, if i click on Home text , it gives document.activeElement as span.

How to get activeElement as anchor tag in IE.

Please help me to go forward.

thanks,SrinivasaRao.CH

Comment: can you put some code?

Comment: Why are you using a <span> inside an <a> element?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are setting your style when link is focused. The below should work in IE too . Can you check ? I am using Mac , so I haven't tested in IE.

```html
<style>
a:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
<form>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tabIndex=0> <span> Home </span> </a>
</form>
```